# What is the adverb for physics?

Tags: word-request, adverbs

When I want to use the adverb for chemistry then I say "chemically", but when I want to use verb for "physics" and I write "physically" it means something else according to my dictionary, while I'm looking for the adverb for physics (science).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use a different dictionary

> [4. pertaining to the physical sciences, especially physics.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/physically)